# Wcf call from one method to another method in the same service

Tags: wcf

Can a wcf call be made from one service method to another method in the same service, exactly when the first method has returned a response? This is required as i need to trigger a call to an external service once the first call being made by that external service has returned a response back to them. Some kind of a trigger that would initiate a call to them, without them calling my method again.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking to achieve here. Maybe if you post some concrete code and examples you could get advice on other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Service A calls Service B, and then some action X has to happen in Service A after the response is received from Service B. Is there a reason that Service B has to trigger that action? Why can't Service A take the appropriate action itself after it receives the response?

Comment: External service calls => my service method 1. Now once they get a response from my service method 1. My service method 2 should be triggered automatically and this would in turn call the external service method 2. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you would have to have your service schedule the "call back" to occur at some arbitrary time in the future.

Comment: Okay, but the first response would reach the external service ryt? Or would that happen only after the callback

Comment: That would depend on which protocols, transports and bindings your services were configured to use. "Guaranteed delivery" is a complex topic when it comes to network protocols. Your service will know that the response was sent (and perhaps that it was successfully received), but you'll have no idea if was yet processed (which might be important in your "call back" scenario).

Comment: Hmm okay.. Ill probably check out the call back option a bit more then. Thank you.